# I wrote this C program for Jacobi iterative method but I am getting Nan and infinity as output I tried changing from

Tags: c

1. I am getting Nan and infinity as output I tried changing  from `float` to `double`
2. Maybe error is in accuracy ?

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <conio.h>
   #include <math.h>

   double u(double w,double x,double y,double z)
   {
     return ( (-22*x+2*y-4*z+3)/3);
   }

   double f(double w,double x,double y,double z)
   {
     return ((36*w+y-3*z-4)/2);

   }

   double s(double w,double x,double y,double z)
   {
     return ((w-2*x-40*z+6)/4);

   }

   double t(double w,double x,double y,double z)
   {
     return ((-2*w-3*x-38*y+8)/2);

   }

   void main()
   {
     double w0,x0,y0,z0,w1=0,x1=0,y1=0,z1=0,tempw,tempx,tempy,tempz,acc=0.000001;
     int iteration=0;
     printf("Enter initial guesses:\n");
     scanf("%f%f%f%f",&w0,&x0,&y0,&z0);
     do
     {
       tempw=w1;
       tempx=x1;
       tempy=y1;
       tempz=z1;
       w1=u(w0,x0,y0,z0);
       x1=f(w0,x0,y0,z0);
       y1=s(w0,x0,y0,z0);
       z1=t(w0,x0,y0,z0);

       iteration++;
       w0=w1;
       x0=x1;
       y0=y1;
       z0=z1;
     }while(fabs(tempw-w1)>acc &&fabs(tempx-x1)>acc && fabs(tempy-y1)>acc 
         && fabs(tempz-z1)>acc);

     printf("\n\nFinally,\n");
     printf("w=%f Ans\nx=%f Ans\ny=%f Ans\nz=%f Ans\n",w1,x1,y1,z1);
     printf("Iteration=%d",iteration);
     getch();

   }
   ```

Comment: sorry if its written poorly its my first time posting here

Comment: Review `double w0,x0,y0,z0;
 
  scanf("%f%f%f%f",&w0,&x0,&y0,&z0);`  Enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read into `double`s using a conversion specifier used for `float` . 
This can lead to undefined behavior

```
scanf("%f%f%f%f",&w0,&x0,&y0,&z0);
```

You need to use `%lf` instead of `%f`.

Some compilers with an appropriate option will give a warning (GCC does this with `-Wall` option).

```
warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float *', but argument 2 has type 'double *' [-Wformat=]    
   scanf("%f%f%f%f",&w0,&x0,&y0,&z0);

          ~^        ~~~    
          %lf
```

The C standard states:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.